# PHP DateTime getTimestamp not working with time earlier 13 Dec 1901

Tags: php, apache, datetime

My environment: `Apache 2.4.27`, `php 5.6.31`, `64-bit architecture`.

Sample code:

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->setDate(1900,1,1);
$date->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$time = $date->getTimestamp();
```

value of `$time` is `false`. As I tested, `getTimestamp` works only on the range `14 Dec 1901 - 19 Jan 2038`.

I googled, but not found any solution. If you have any ideals, please share with me!

P/s: the sample code is a part of Moodle core. So please don't suggest to change the code!

Comment: @Pang, I already read this post. My code used `DateTime` class, my PHP version is `5.6` and the architecture is `64-bit`, so the post isn't really helpful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) in reverse.

There is a limit to the values that 64 bits can hold, and you have found it.

PHP uses Linux timestamps, which count seconds after (and, in your case, before) midnight on 1st Jan 1970.

If you take the max negative value that 64 bits can hold , as seconds, and subtract that from 1st Jan 1970 (aka the Epoch), you get the limit which you have found

Comment: Thank you for your help. My Apache is 64-bit but php is 32-bit actually. It is the root cause.